# ISP connections Vs IX Connections

Tags: isp, peering

I would like to know the difference between ISP connections and IX connections? Basically we are evaluating some of the ISPs to get our edge circuits. While doing some research on it, came across to peering connections to IX locations. How do they help us? When I search in peering database, companies are having ISP links as well as IX links. How do they use it? Any pointers will be helpful? Sorry if it is a beginner question, could not find the correct difference and usage of these two models.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet is really just a bunch of networks connected together. Consumers and businesses connect to ISPs as customers. ISPs connect to other ISPs, either as customers of larger ISPs, or as peers at Internet Exchange Points (IXPs). At IXPs, ISPs can often peer with multiple other ISPs and CDNs, reducing costs by having a single location for connections, instead of running connections to multiple places in order to connect to multiple peers.

Comment: But, for example if you check any enterprise or cloud service provider in peeringdb, in addition to multiple ISP connections, they also peer publically in IXs. In this case, how they use this peering line? They send their traffic through this line, if so why they have multiple ISP connections also?

Comment: This is a different question, and you should really ask it in a different question, although it's actually off-topic since questions about networks over which you have no control are off topic, and you would really need to ask the provider(s), but if you were a cloud provider, and there was an ISP which, itself, was your customer, and/or the ISP had many or important or high-paying customers of yours, what would you do? It makes sense to have as direct a connection as possible to your customers, or your competition may win their business.